# Kindle Unlimited in the Amazon Advertising API

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services

Working on a project using the Amazon Advertising API (I'm using PHP, not sure if that matters) and I would just like to know if there is anyway to tell if a book is included in Kindle Unlimited from any of the response groups?

I have been crawling through them for ages and I assume there must be some kind of indication but I can't spot one anywhere...

Comment: Any luck with finding how to use Kindle Unlimited books in the response groups?  I can't find any answer to this. Maybe there is no way?

Comment: It's been a while since I had a look but the most recent version of the API seems to offer no indication at all